# ion-split-pane isn't working as expected

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to add the split pane to my first view just as say in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/), but it isn't working with ionic serve or ionic deploy browser.

I'm using the following:

cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.11.0
npm  : 5.6.0 
OS   : Linux 4.15
```

And the code for the view is this:

```
<ion-split-pane when="xs">
  <!-- Side Menu -->
  <ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menuClose ion-item detail-none *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
          {{p.title}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <!-- Content -->
  <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" main #content></ion-nav>
</ion-split-pane>
```

I don't now if there was some change from ionic 3 to 4 that wasn't added to the documentation or if I need to add something else for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the ionic template super and for some reason it has two menus, one in the app.module.ts template and one  as a page.

The one on app.ts looks like this:

```
@Component({
  // Menu lateral
  template: `<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Olá</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <button menuClose ion-item detail-none *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
          {{p.title}}
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

  </ion-menu>
  <ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
```

So I changed it to :

```
@Component({
  template: `<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
```

And now the ion-split-pane pane is working without any problem.